# .NET Core 3.0 : getting a type cast error when trying to retrieve option values using .Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following piece of code where I get the JWT options set in `StartUp.cs`.

First here is where I set the `TokenOptions` in `StartUp.cs` in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
// Get jwt options from app settings
var tokenOptions = _configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Get<JwtTokenOptions>();

services.AddAuthentication(x => {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenOptions.SigningKey)),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
});
```

This works I think and I set the options there.

Now I want to use those options in a class using dependency injection:

```
using JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.CATALOG.ENTITIES;
using JobsLedger.CATALOG.Repositories.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace JobsLedger.AUTHORISATION
{
    public class UserAuthorisationServices : IUserAuthorisationServices
    {
        #region Variables
        private readonly IUserCATALOGRepository _userCATALOGRepository;
        private readonly IRoleCATALOGRepository _roleCATALOGRepository;
        private readonly ICryptoService _cryptoService;
        IOptions<TokenOptions> _tokenOptions;
        #endregion

        public UserAuthorisationServices(IUserCATALOGRepository userCATALOGRepository,
                            IRoleCATALOGRepository roleCATALOGRepository,
                            ICryptoService cryptoService,
                            IOptions<TokenOptions> tokenOptions)
        {
            _userCATALOGRepository = userCATALOGRepository;
            _roleCATALOGRepository = roleCATALOGRepository;
            _cryptoService = cryptoService;
            _tokenOptions = tokenOptions.Value;
        }
```

Problem is.. I am getting a type error on this line:

```
_tokenOptions = tokenOptions.Value;
```

and the error is:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TokenOptions' to 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So this is failing despite the fact I am using `IOptions<TokenOptions>` in both cases.

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: wouldnt it just be `_tokenOptions = tokenOptions;`

Comment: `.Value` will return the actual type within the IOptions. So changing the declared type of `_tokenOptions` to simply `TokenOptions` should do it

Comment: I was working off the assumption I had to inject the values from the options.. will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `.Value` property inside the `IOptions<T>` which is type `T` to set a member in your class of type `IOptions<T>`. Since `IOptions<T>` is not `T`, you are getting an error.

You can either change the member

```
IOptions<TokenOptions> _tokenOptions;
```

to

```
TokenOptions _tokenOptions;
```

or change within your constructor

```
_tokenOptions = tokenOptions.Value;
```

to

```
_tokenOptions = tokenOptions;
```